# Search data stored on memory for particular string

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-memory, flash-memory

Is it possible to search data stored on memory for particular string?
Example: we want display memory contents corresponding to particular string in code, is possible search for this string and corresponding value in memory?

Comment: Memory of what? What's the use case?

Comment: display value for the particular strings, the strings/values are stored in config, nvram.